# SQL / MySQL: How to check "AND" logic that similar to "OR" in "WHERE IN"

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I have 2 tables named `item` and `tag`. They have a many-to-many relationship so their join table is `item_tag` as below.

```
-- item table
id  name
1   Item 1
2   Item 2
3   Item 3

-- tag table
id  name
1   Tag 1
2   Tag 2
3   Tag 3

-- item_tag table
item_id tag_id
1       1
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       3
```

I need a SQL query to get items which have **both** `Tag 1` and `Tag 2` (**AND** operation for given tag ids = (1, 2)).

Which means,

```
-- Expected output
id  name
2   Item 2
```

Only `Item 2` has **both** the `Tag 1` and `Tag 2`
so it should be **AND** logic for the tags.

[`WHERE IN` gives **OR** logic similarly for this scenario so cannot use it]

Can someone please help me to write that query?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `(item_id, tag_id)` is defined as UNIQUE?

Comment: Yes the combination of (item_id, tag_id) should be unique in this case

Comment: I don't ask should it be unique or not. I ask does unique index by these columns exists in the table structure. If not then these columns combination may contain duplicates, and nothing prevents this.

Comment: @MihiranParanamana do you know the tag ids you need to check? like in above example 1 & 2

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress Yes, it comes from the front-end side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> get items which have both Tag 1 and Tag 2

```sql
SELECT *
FROM item
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM item_tag 
               WHERE item.id = item_tag.item_id
                 AND tag_id = 1 )
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM item_tag 
               WHERE item.id = item_tag.item_id
                 AND tag_id = 2 )
```

---

> when I have more tag ids, this query needs to be modified by adding the subquery for each tag ids.

The query which does not need in modifying:

```sql
SELECT item.id, item.name
FROM item
JOIN item_tag ON item.id = item_tag.item_id
WHERE item_tag.tag_id IN ( {tags list} )
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT item_tag.tag_id ) = {tags list length}
```

If UNIQUE index by `(item_id, tag_id)` exists in `item_tag` table structure then DISTINCT may be removed.

If you have tags names list, not ids list, then:

```sql
SELECT item.id, item.name
FROM item
JOIN item_tag ON item.id = item_tag.item_id
JOIN tag ON item_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE tag,name IN ( {tag names list} )
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT item_tag.tag_id ) = {tags list length}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I have more tag ids, this query needs to be modified by adding the subquery for each tag ids. isn't it?

Comment: Second part of your answer is very reminiscent of mine.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Visually true, but it is reminiscent only. `MIN(t.id) <> MAX(t.id)` works with 2-entry list only.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.name
FROM item i
INNER JOIN item_tag it ON it.item_id = i.id
INNER JOIN tag t ON t.id = it.tag_id
WHERE t.name IN ('Tag 1', 'Tag 2')
GROUP BY i.id, i.name
HAVING MIN(t.id) <> MAX(t.id);
```

Note: Use the following `HAVING` clause to support an arbitrary number of tags:

```sql
HAVING(COUNT DISTINCT t.id) = 2  -- replace 2 by number of tags
```

Comment: When I add 'Tag 3' as well into the IN () part, it will return 'Item 2' and 'Item 3'. But it should not return any, because there is no item here which has all the tags. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Check my updated answer.  You can use the alternative `HAVING` clause.